# Play internet video in external players (cross-platform)?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, flash, gpu, cross-platform

I have created a [similar question on this on the ubuntu page](https://askubuntu.com/q/169622/47206). While that question was directed to a certain problem with adobe flash player in Linux, the answer that I found in the end is cross-platform and may be  found useful here as a solution on most operating systems.

So, the idea is to play an embedded video from the internet by sending the URL stream to a video player installed on the computer and thus take advantage of the player's features (like changing aspect ratio, video and audio settings, using subtitles, etc), and also possibly put less pressure on the GPU resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a cross-platform solution for this, just use the **Firefox addon [FlashGot](http://flashgot.net/)**, which is meant to send video streams to different download managers. What if it were used to **send the URL stream to VLC**, for example?

- add VLC to Flashgot list: FlashGot options, General tab, Add, give a name 'VLC' , - then go to the VLC executable and select it

[image]
[image]

- FlashGot options, FlashGot tab, choose VLC

[image]

- playing the video in Firefox, a Flashgot button should appear (add that to the toolbar or the status bar). Right-click the button, Available formats, and left-click the video. VLC should start playing the video stream

[image]

**UPDATE**:

After more testing `mpv` seems better than VLC  for this purpose.

Other players can also be used in this way (in Windows, PotPlayer, MPC-HC, BSPlayer).

---

Also in Firefox, [OpenWith](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/open-with/) addon.

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**Drag & drop**:

On Youtube, after searching a term and getting a list of titles, dragging&dropping a name onto a player may start playing the video.

Not all video players work like this, and also late 2016 Firefox and Chrome doesn't seem to work in this way in Linux. But testing in Linux, it works with Seamonkey, Palemoon, Epiphany or Icecat browsers by dropping the title from Youtube in `mpv` and other front-ends for `mpv` like Gnome MPV and SMPlayer.

[image]

In Windows, it works in both Firefox and Chrome by dropping the title onto  MPC-HC.

Comment: also: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/32137/22326