# VLC problems with external subtitles for a DVD movie

Tags: dvd, vlc-media-player, subtitles

I was looking for ways to [use external subtitles with DVD movies](https://superuser.com/q/719331/162573) and have found several solutions (amongst others, MPC-HC).

But I was surprised that VLC was not a solution here - and I imagine some settings are possible. I have tested different settings for the Video Output, but then the subs disappeared etc  when for a moment it seemed to work: **subtitles may disappear from time to time or appear for too short a time, or they may fully disappear after seeking back or forth withing the video**.

I have tested this in Mac, Windows and Linux.

Are there some tweaks under the hood in order to make it work in VLC?

Comment: for reference an answer that does not provide a solution - [here](http://superuser.com/a/719334/162573)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you have to do is open the subtitle file in VLC's Menu Bar.

*Subtitles > Add Subtitle File...*

[image: Add an external subtitle file to VLC while watching a video]

Browse for an appropriate subtitle file (example: subtitles.srt)

If the subtitles are not synced with your audio, use the `h` and `j` keys to adjust subtitle delay offset.

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear enough. I will try to make it clearer. What you show is how to add the subtitles, which is useful but was by no means a mystery. The problem was that the external subs for dvds are not properly displayed in VLC: subtitles are not displayed all the time, and/or disappear after seeking back or forth  the video. - Also, I see you tested on a Mac. I have no dvd player connected to my macbook, but as far as I can tell (by playing local dvd folders), the 2.2.6 VLC version for Mac has the same problems. - Is your system not affected by this?

Comment: I understand now. I'm using version 2.2.5.1 on Windows, and version 2.2.4 on OSX. I also don't have a DVD player on my Mac. I can reproduce your problem on my windows computer with a DVD, and I cannot offer a solution. To play the DVD on my Mac, I first ripped the video using Handbrake, working around the issue on that computer.